# Wordpress ignores php.ini settings on Google App Engine PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I'm trying to raise the upload limits of my Wordpress (MultiSite) running on Google App Engine PHP.

I followed the instructions on 
to create an and php.ini file with this contents

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
memory_limit = 64M
```

and these values are visible if I do a phpinfo(); - but wordpress keeps ignoring them.
(I also tried increasing the memory in wp-config.php)

Am I missing something?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is Wordpress MULTISITE and the additional settings it's creates.

There is a upload limit setting in the Network Settings Panel called "Max upload file size".

If that is set higher than the upload limits in php.ini or .htaccess - those limits apply - so in the end you have to set both.

Once I've looked up wordpress multisite upload limit the solution was easily be found. Sorry if I was wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

memory_limit is ignored by app engine, it's configured by your instance size that you set in the admin console.

The other 2 should work - php reads them from php.ini. Can you describe what you mean by WordPress ignores them?

Comment: thank you about clarification for memory_limit. What I meant was that I can see that PHP picks up the values from php.ini (I see them in phpinfo()) but wordpress doesn't allow larger post sizes - but I found a solution ... see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please read carefully. First read about what AppEngine is or how it works. When you do that, you don't need to ask anymore to PHP files parsing questions, that includes apache's .htaccess, or php.ini and some other tricks like ini_set().

You can set theese type of settings on AppEngine because it is not "the normal hosting server". It is a platform to develop app's with PHP support. Is not the same thing and sometimes configure it is a pain compared to the usual way.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using fcgi check the fcgid.conf setting for  max requestlen. The most less value of the setting is used

...
    FcgidMaxRequestLen 134217728
    ...

service apache2 restart

Comment: this might work under a normal LAMP installation - but GAE uses it's own server.py to simulate the AppEngine enviroment in local machines.